# Modifying Ajax post request data using dojo/notify api

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, dojo

I am trying to attach a Form data variable to Ajax Post Request using DOJO/NOTIFY. For example: there is a form which sends an item **a = 10** to the server. **Using dojo/notify (send)** I attach another variable **b=5** with the ajax post request **but the problem is that it does not work and only a=10 is sent to server**. Following is my code:

```
require(["dojo/request", "dojo/request/notify"], function (Request, Notify) {

    //Called before sending Ajax Request
    Notify("send", function (request) {
        dojo.byId("status").innerHTML = "Sending Ajax Request";
        /*
          At this point I want to add another form data item before 
          it is sent to Server.Example b = 5. The following is the 
          way to do it but It does not seem to work:
        */

        request.options.data += "&b=5";
        //I also tries the following but it also not working:
        //request.options.data.b = "5";     
    });

    Request.post("http://jsfiddle.net/",{
        data:{a:10}
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TEMA2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/request/notify` was never made for these purposes. The response you get from it is only used for providing you a notification, it's not used in the request for further processing, so your modifications are actually ignored.

To intercept calls, you should rather be looking at the [`dojo/request/registry`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/registry.html) module, which you can use to register providers (which can be used as interceptors).

For example, if you want to add data to your request you could use:

```js
Registry.register(function(url, options) {
    options.data.b = 5;
    return true;
}, Request, true);

Registry.post("/echo/json",{
    data:{a:10}
});
```

So in this case I'm sending a `POST` request with `a=10`, also notice that I'm no longer sending the request using the `dojo/request` module, but by using the `dojo/request/registry` module (I'm using `Registry.post()`).

This module will then look for an appropriate provider, and in this case we registered a provider that will always return `true`, which means it will always be used.

In that provider we're changing the `options.data` object and add an extra attribute to it. The other attributes in the `Registry.register()` function are:

- `Request`: Tells the provider system that we want to use the `dojo/request` module to handle the call
- `true`: Tells you that this provider should be used as the first provider (it has higher priority)

So in fact we add an extra abstraction layer to the request that makes intercepting calls possible.

I also updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TEMA2/2/

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Your code works perfectly. Can there be a general hook which get called before sending an Ajax post request to server and modify data. I mean we do not care whether the request is sent through dojo/request, dojo/registry, jQuery/xhr or simple xmlhttprequest...Just need to modify the request before sending it to server.

Comment: If you want such think you will have to override the `XMLHttpRequest` prototype. You might find some libraries that will do such thing, but not in Dojo (as far as I know).